# Issue to determine a currently downloading file size?

Tags: php

I have an interesting problem. I need to do a progress bar from an asycronusly php file downloading. I thought the best way to do it is before the download starts the script is making a txt file which is including the file name and the original file size as well.

Now we have an ajax function which calling a php script what is intended to check the local file size. I have 2 main problems.

1. files are bigger then 2GB so filesize() function is out of business
2. i tried to find a different way to determine the local file size like this:

.

```
  function getSize($filename) { 

       $a = fopen($filename, 'r'); 
       fseek($a, 0, SEEK_END); 
       $filesize = ftell($a); 
       fclose($a);
       return $filesize;
  }
```

Unfortunately the second way giving me a tons of error assuming that i cannot open a file which is currently downloading.

Is there any way i can check a size of a file which is currently downloading and the file size will be bigger then 2 GB?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered to skip PHP completely and use HTTP HEAD request to get the file size directly from web server?

Comment: Milan your way is looking very interesting can you give me a code sample how to do that or can you express more your thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by using an exec() function:

```
exec("ls -s -k /path/to/your/file/".$file_name,$out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your OS and PHP to support 64 bit computing. and you can still use filesize().
From filesize() manual:

> Return Values
>
> Returns the size of the file in bytes, or FALSE (and generates an
>   error of level E_WARNING) in case of an error.
>
> Note: Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use
>   32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected
>   results for files which are larger than 2GB.

Comment: if i use filesize() im receiving this error: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for . I'm using Linux for developing but it will be running on windows. Both systems are 64 Bit.

Comment: are you using full path for filesize? `filesize("/full/path/to/download/file");`

Comment: Are you sure permission is correct? Chmod 777 for example? Check PHP log file to know what's happen